# How to control height and padding of GeometryReader

Tags: swiftui

I have two Text Fields side-by-side. The first field should take up 25% of the width and the second field 75%. I also have a view modifier that adds 24px of horizontal padding.

Two issues

1. The second Text Filed does not respect the Horizontal padding on the right side. How do I get it to respect the padding?
2. The whole Geometry Reader is a square, its vertical size seams to match the horizontal.  How do I get it to just conform to the height of the TextFields.

   ```
      GeometryReader { geometry in HStack(spacing: 20) {
      TextField("Country...", text: $country)
        .textFieldStyle(TextFieldDarkFull())
        .frame(
          width: geometry.size.width * 0.25
         )
      TextField("Phone...", text: $phone)
        .textFieldStyle(TextFieldDarkFull())
        .frame(
          width: geometry.size.width * 0.75
         )
    }
    }
    .modifier(HorizontalPadding24())
   ```

Comment: Try removing the padding from the width. (geometry.size.width - 48)

Answer (score 2):

1. remove second `TextField` frame limitation (ie. modifier `width: geometry.size.width * 0.75`). So you fix first text field and let second one consume all remaining space dynamically.
2. it depends of your entire layout but you can try to fix vertical size of block, like

```
     GeometryReader { geometry in HStack(spacing: 20) {
        // content here
     }
     .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)     // << here !!
```

Comment: Removing the second .75 absolutely fixed the width issue.  And makes perfect sense now.  Thank you!

The .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true) changed the vertical issue.  Now the content below the geometry reader overlaps on top of the reader content.